# How to do routing in angular2 without binding a path to a component?

Tags: angular

Context: I'm trying to add routing to my TodoMVC implementation of angular2:
https://github.com/ng2-dart-samples/todomvc

The official todomvc of angular2 doesn't have routing yet, so that doesn't help: https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/examples/angular2

I've been looking into some other angular 2 routing examples. And I understand the examples where they bind some path to a component class. But I want to use routing, to mainly filter some elements in a todolist, I don't want to bind it to a complete component. So my question is, is this possible ?

I could achieve it in some little bit hacky way:

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/', component: TodoComponent, as: 'all'),
  const Route(path: '/active', component: TodoComponent, as: 'active'),
  const Route(path: '/completed', component: TodoComponent, as: 'completed'),
])
class App {}
```

And then listen for changes in the the child component:

```
class TodoComponent {
  Router router;
  String filter;
  TodoStore todoStore;

  TodoComponent(this.todoStore, this.router) {
    router.parent.subscribe((String value) => filter = value);
  }
}
```

I would hope that there is a bit more straight forward way to do this. For example, some code like this:

```
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(path: '/'),
  const Route(path: '/active'),
  const Route(path: '/completed'),
])
class TodoComponent {
  Router router;
  String filter;
  TodoStore todoStore;

  TodoComponent(this.todoStore, this.router) {
    router.subscribe((String value) => filter = value);
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work. Any other options. Or is something like this just not implemented yet?

Comment: This might not be what you are looking for, but can't you just add a route with a parameter {path: '/todo/:status', component: TodoComponent, as: 'todoComponent'}. Then use  params.get('status'); to get your filter from the route? Example here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0

Comment: @TGH thanks, I implemented it now like you suggested